# USPS priority and express options not showing up

Tags: shipping, usps

This is a really odd scenario I have going on here. If I checkout with 1 or 2 items in my cart First Class Mail Parcel shows up as an option. If I check out with more than 2 items (each item is btwn .3 to .4 lbs) then the only USPS option disappears. 
I cannot get any kind of Priority or Express to show up for any item regardless of count.

Any ideas of what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Did you get this resolved?  The First Class option goes away once the total weight exceeds 13 oz (0.8125).  As far as Priority and Express, make sure you have all your desired options selected in the Allowed Methods. My settings (for comparison - I am using CE 1.9.1) are Request type: Divide to equal weight, Container: Variable, Size: Regular, Machinable: No. You can also try turning on the Debug option for USPS and then check your var/log/ after you try checking out again.